# Getting a pop Up when loading data from IBM informix to SQL DB

Tags: ssis, informix

For my SSIS package,  source is  IBM informix database and the destination is SQL server. Everything is fine. Even I'm able to load the data from source to destination. But, gets the below pop up as shown below almost 20 times for lat-least loading 1000 records then i should i say ok then it will proceed further.

[image]

it is Configured as a ODBC connection as shown below.

[image]
Please help.

Thanks,

Vikram

Answer (score 2):

Ummm. kind of the error is self-explanatory ;)

You are using an Informix ODBC driver from DataDirect which was licensed to be used only with an Oracle client.

You should use the Informix ODBC driver (from IBM/HCL) instead of that one from DataDirect.
Download Informix ClientSDK from https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/tnd/search.jsp?rs=ifxdl or use the CSDK media that came with the engine.

After the installation you should have an ODBC driver ('IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER' or 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)' registered on your Windows box which you can use to connect to Informix from SSIS

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving large amounts of data with SSIS or simplify the deployment of the informix client, you can also evaluate an open version of the [Informix ODBC connector](https://www.progress.com/odbc/ibm-informix) distributed by IBM here.

Regardless of which driver you try, you'll need both a 32-bit ODBC driver for your BIDS development environment and 64-bit for run-time.

Note that I am employed by Progress.